# Not able to switch window and shift control to new window in UI automation using WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, ui-automation, chai, webdriver-io

I am trying to automation of a UI page where, on click of a button opens up another window. I want to switch control to the new window and perform some operation on the new window.

I tried using browser.windowHandles , browser.switchTab(), and browser.switchWindow().

SwitchWindow() helps switching to new window, but control remains in the old window itself.

For example, If I want to perform a click() operation it gets clicked in the older window instead of clicking on the new window.

What method can I use to switch to different window and shift control to new window.